# tensorboard embeddings show no data

Tags: tensorboard

I am rying to use  tensorboard embeddings  page  in order to  visualize the results of word2vec. After debugging, digging of  lots of codes  i  came to  a point that  tensorboard successfully runs, reads the confguration file, reads the tsv files but  now the embeddings page does not show data.
 ( the  page  is opened , i can see the menus , items etc)  this is  my config file:
embeddings {
  tensor_name: 'word_embedding'
  metadata_path: 'c:\data\metadata.tsv'
  tensor_path: 'c:\data\tensors2.tsv'
}

What can be  the  problem?

The tensor file originally is  1gb. in size,  if i try that file ,  the app crashes becasue of the  memory. So i  copy and paste 1 or 2 pages of the  original file  into  tensor2.tsv and use this file.  May  be this is the  problem.  May  be i  need to create  more data by copy/ paste.

thx
tolga

Answer (score 0):

Try following code snippet to get visualized word embedding in tensorboard. Open tensorboard with logdir, check localhost:6006 for viewing your embedding.

> tensorboard --logdir="visual/1"

```
# code
fname = "word2vec_model_1000"
model = gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.load(fname)
# project part of vocab, max of 100 dimension
max = 1000

w2v = np.zeros((max,100))
with open("prefix_metadata.tsv", 'w+') as file_metadata:
    for i,word in enumerate(model.wv.index2word[:max]):
        w2v[i] = model.wv[word]
        file_metadata.write(word + '\n')

# define the model without training
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    embedding = tf.Variable(w2v, trainable=False, name='prefix_embedding')

tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

path = 'visual/1'
saver = tf.train.Saver()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(path, sess.graph)

# adding into projector
config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
embed= config.embeddings.add()
embed.tensor_name = 'prefix_embedding'
embed.metadata_path = 'prefix_metadata.tsv'

# Specify the width and height of a single thumbnail.
projector.visualize_embeddings(writer, config)

saver.save(sess, path+'/prefix_model.ckpt', global_step=max)
```